# How to perform a Window Function operation in a Pandas Dataframe using a cumulative sum?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by

I have an initial dataframe

```
df1 = 
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1| 10|
|  1|  2| 11|
|  1|  2| 12|
|  3|  1| 13|
|  2|  1| 14|
|  2|  1| 15|
|  2|  1| 16|
|  4|  1| 17|
|  4|  2| 18|
|  4|  3| 19|
|  4|  4| 19|
|  4|  5| 20|
|  4|  5| 20|
+---+---+---+
```

Using pyspark I coded the dataframe with a window function using a sum taking into account the column 'A' and taking into account the column 'B' sorted.

```
spec = Window.partitionBy('A').orderBy('B')
df1 = df1.withColumn('D',sum('C').over(spec))

df1.show()

+---+---+---+-----+
|  A|  B|  C|    D|
+---+---+---+-----+
|  1|  1| 10| 10.0|
|  1|  2| 11| 33.0|
|  1|  2| 12| 33.0|
|  2|  1| 14| 45.0|
|  2|  1| 15| 45.0|
|  2|  1| 16| 45.0|
|  3|  1| 13| 13.0|
|  4|  1| 17| 17.0|
|  4|  2| 18| 35.0|
|  4|  3| 19| 54.0|
|  4|  4| 19| 73.0|
|  4|  5| 20|113.0|
|  4|  5| 20|113.0|
+---+---+---+-----+
```

Is it possible to do the same calculation using Pandas Dataframe?

I tried using

`df['D'] = df.sort_values(['A','B']).groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform('cumsum')`

but it is not the same result

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pandas we can [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) on `A` and `B`. Then [`groupby cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) just over `A`. To add results back to the DataFrame [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) to the new column name then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the results back to the DataFrame on the initial group keys `['A', 'B']`:

```
df1 = df1.join(
    df1.groupby(by=['A', 'B'])['C'].sum()
        .groupby(level='A').cumsum()
        .rename('D'),
    on=['A', 'B']
)
```

`df1`:

```
    A  B   C    D
0   1  1  10   10
1   1  2  11   33
2   1  2  12   33
3   3  1  13   13
4   2  1  14   45
5   2  1  15   45
6   2  1  16   45
7   4  1  17   17
8   4  2  18   35
9   4  3  19   54
10  4  4  19   73
11  4  5  20  113
12  4  5  20  113
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    'B': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
    'C': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `sort`, then `cumsum` within 'A', then `groupby` + `max` within ['A', 'B'] groups using `transform` so you can assign the result back.

```
df1['D'] = (df1.sort_values(['A', 'B'])
               .groupby('A')['C'].cumsum()
               .groupby([df1['A'], df1['B']]).transform('max'))
```

---

```
    A  B   C    D
0   1  1  10   10
1   1  2  11   33
2   1  2  12   33
3   3  1  13   13
4   2  1  14   45
5   2  1  15   45
6   2  1  16   45
7   4  1  17   17
8   4  2  18   35
9   4  3  19   54
10  4  4  19   73
11  4  5  20  113
12  4  5  20  113
```